# Isotope masonry, not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co). Testing the reLayout method by using the example provided here (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html), copied the css, js to (http://punkbit.com/webzine/isotope.html) but when I click in the first element all other elements go to the first column. I wonder why this happens ?

If we do the same in the official example, it works properly, apparently!

I'd like to toggle a class in the first element and by doing that, having the other elements take the vertical space and positioned properly. I tried to change the width of the container, etc but no success!

I've also got the same issue happening with Masonry:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKAdH

If clicking in the first element, it won't work. All elements will be placed in the first column.

- Also tried different layout modes etc without success

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,
I've found the answer:

http://punkbit.com/webzine/isotope2.html

The property "columnWidth" needs to be set.

For Masonry:

http://codepen.io/helderoliveira/pen/gwvjA